# SSRS Page breaks in Column groups

Tags: reporting-services

I have a data set the has citys and citygroup and other columns with the details for each city. there are 8 city and 2 citygroups ( city 1 to 4 is groupA and city 5 - 8 is groupB)

I have a Column group in my ssrs report with city

I need help with adding page breaks so that groupA is on page 1 and group B is in page two

I tried adding a parent group with citygroups but nothing works

I new to ssrs and need some help with this

Comment: If you right click on the grouping and click on group properties -> Page Breaks -> Between each instance of the group. then it should break each group onto a new page

Comment: I have tried that and even added an if statement still nothing

Comment: can you show a screen shot of your design screen ?